# Get file from remote host with Fabric and serve it directly in Django view

Tags: python, django, fabric

I have a setup of two servers, where one runs a Django web server and the other stores files. I own the web server, but I only have ssh access to the storage server as a regular user.

I wanted to make it possible for the user to download files, using the web interface, directly from the storage server.

The path of the file on the storage server will be built based on parameters passed to the view.

I have solved the problem using Fabric to download the file, and I will post what I did as an answer, because I think more people can benefit from it, as I didn't find another question on SO addressing this specific issue.

But I would like to hear opinions and other, possibly better, solutions, or problems that could come from my solution. Also if there is another way to do this using another tool than Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of the view I'm currently using to solve the problem:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def download_file(request, remote_path):
    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
    from fabric.api import env, get, execute
    from mimetypes import guess_type

    # This will be passed to Fabric's execute function
    hosts = ['storage_server_IP']
    # Setting the user and password of the remote server on Fabric environment
    env.password = 'my_password'
    env.user = 'my_user'

    # Function to be executed on remote server
    def get_file(remote_path):
        from StringIO import StringIO

        fb = StringIO()
        get(remote_path, fb)

        # This will return a string holding the file content
        return fb.getvalue()

    result_dict = execute(get_file, remote_path, hosts=hosts)
    # The execute function returns a dict where the hosts are the keys and the return of the called function (get_file in this case) are the values, so we get only the value of our only host
    content = result_dict[hosts[0]]

    # Creates a file from the string that holds the content
    my_file = ContentFile(content)
    my_file.name = remote_path.split('/')[-1]
    # This guesses the mime_type of the file, based on its extension
    mime_type = guess_type(my_file.name)

    response = HttpResponse(my_file, content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + my_file.name
    return response
```

Comment: This post is quite old but I would be interested with your experience. I want to develop an Django app that should be able to retrieve files (csv) from a remote server and store it locally. I wonder if your code (or a new solution) could help me